# How I can organize run configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I have organize my favorite "run configurations" but I have a lot of favorite.
So I would like to know if a plugin exists that permit to create folders or sub-lists to have a better view and organization of my run configurations.

I would like this because when I click on the "arrow" near "Run" button on the top of the Eclipse toolbar I have a very long list and it's diffuclt to find quickly the "run configuration" that I want.

I hope somebody have an idea and can help me.
Thanks.

Sincerely,
Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to help a little bit:

1. If you are more interested in the last started run configurations, these get a number. Number 1 is the last, number 2 the previous before and so on.
2. Press `ALT-SHIFT-X` followed by the type of run configuration (`j` for Java), and you get a list of run configurations. Type in the filter box, and select by cursor keys.
3. Under `Run > Organize Favorites ...` you have the option to mark some of them as the ones you want to use often. These will listed at the top of the selection list then.
4. `Run configurations... > Filtering Preferences...` will open the preferences where you are able to define which filter should be used for the run configurations. If you use Working Sets in your programming, this could be helpful, so by switching Working Set, the run configurations come with it.

I think the keyboard shortcut is the fastest one if you want to use the run configurations all. If there is a special order, the first tip by be sufficient. If your context changes, and the run configurations should change as well, use the working sets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, however it might help future readers.

Well, if you want to manage your Run Configurations I would recommend you  [Eclipse Runner](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner) plugin.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugin that does that, but in Eclipse the chosen run configuration if you hit the run button is the last one ran. Which is what you'll need most of the time, typically. Otherwise you can just go inside the menu, where all configurations are grouped by type and choose from there, that might take a couple more seconds but maybe is not so confusing.

Comment: In my case, I have a list of about 20 favorite "run configurations" and under this list, I fix the number of last run to 1 element, because I only use my favorite "run configuration".
I tried to find a plugin that organize my favorite run configuration but it was a failure.

Thanks for your answer Jubbat but now your solution doesn't help me because want to stay with this list but with less effort to find the good run configuration that I want to launch.

I think I must develop my own plugin to solve my "problem" (it's not really a problem).
I hope someone have the solution.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to save the run configurations as "Stored Files" in various project directories.  This doesn't require saving or loading manually, you just select "Shared file" in the "Common" tab and set it to a project directory.

When you open or close one of these "Projects" (even if that project contains nothing but run configurations) it will show/hide those configurations.

I'm currently considering creating some "Fake" projects just to hold launcher groups.